# jquery table sorting with plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery plugin found at:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

I was able to get it to work on a static table. But now I am trying to get it to work on a table that is filled from a database with ajax. I feel am putting this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ $("#myTable").tablesorter(); } );
```

in the wrong spot. I just have it in Javascript tags at the top of the page. Since the table keeps getting refreshed I think I might need to call the above code again. Should it go in the ajax call or what?

Comment: jQuery dataTables sounds like a better fit for your needs: http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should execute it inside the ajax success handler where you create the dynamic table. It is because jQuery should be able to find the element on the page before applying the plugin on it. Since you are creating it dynamically it will not find it if you execute the code on `document` ready.

```
$.ajax(function(){
   ..
   success: function(){
        //Other code to create the dynamic table
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
   }
   ..
});
```

**Update:**

If you are emptying the existing rows and just refreshing the same table with new rows(data) then you have to trigger `update` event on the table.

```
$("myTable").trigger("update");
```

Comment: that works after I populate the table, but if Ire-populate the table and then sort the old table pops back up

Comment: I think OP means that the table is static, the table data (tr, td) is what will change after the ajax calls. This code has already created the plugin, so it won't create it again.

Comment: @searayman - I was thinking you are creating a new table. But if you are just refreshing the same table the please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Yes that is correct I am not creating a new table. I am clearing the rows under the header and re-filling.

I tried adding the trigger after my code for adding the new rows.But when I test it and click a column to sort I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
multisortjquery.tablesorter.js:600
$.extend.tablesorter.construct.each.$headers.click.mousedown.onselectstart

Answer (score 1):

Check your plugin documentation, there's probably a way to re-sort it after the data has changed. [This example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-empty-table.html) might be what you're looking for. It creates the table sorter once, with empty data. When the data is inserted, it triggers an update using:

```
$("table").trigger("update");
```

This is the code you should use after each ajax call. Your original code should remain as it is (run it only once). The complete example would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    $.ajax(function(){
        ..
        success: function(){
            // Update your table data (remove and insert tr, tds etc)
            $("#myTable").trigger("update");
            // If your sorting conditions changed, use also:
            $("#myTable").trigger("sorton",[sortingConditions]);
        }
        ..
    });
});
```

(Fragments of code copied from yours and ShankarSangoli's answers)